# Add trailing constraint programmatically

Tags: ios

I would like to stick the label views to the right of the scroll view with the following code
regardless of landscape or potrait but getting the error below.

View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
    Constraint: 
    Container hierarchy: 
>
    View not found in container hierarchy: ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
    That view's superview: >

```
 [descriptionLabel addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:descriptionLabel
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: Please read of how constraints work first. You must always add constraints to the superview. So, you would add this constraint with item descriptionLabel to the scrollView and then specify a constant for the trailing space.

Comment: Have you added the label to the scrollView before doing this? The child view must be added first, before any constraints can be set.